# Persisting a DenseMatrix in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there a recommended/proven to be efficient format or mechanism to persist a DenseMatrix in Apache Spark? Or should I just write it into a file?

I am generating a DenseMatrix post a SVD operation and need to refer to it as and when user queries come in and hence it would be looked up often.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `DenseMatrix` you mean `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix` (V)  it is a local data structure and there is no Spark specific way to handle this type of objects.

One way to handle it is to write a serialized object directly to file:

```scala
val oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(
  new java.io.FileInputStream("/tmp/foo")))

oos.writeObject(svd.V)
oos.close()
```

and read it later using `FileInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream.readObject`. You can also use human readable serialization of your choice like JSON:

```scala
import net.liftweb.json.{NoTypeHints, Serialization}
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.{read, write}
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

val serialized: String = write(svd.V) 
// Write to file and read if needed
...
// Deserialize 
val deserialized = read[DenseMatrix](serialized)
```